# limit textbox to x number of characters

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox on an aspx page which I have limited to accept 250 characters.
This works fine when a user just types data in, but if they paste the textbox will accept way more.
Is there a way I can get around this? I dont want to disable pasting in the textbox though.

thanks again

Comment: Do you want to trim the extra characters after 250?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a validator to the page which will check the string length.
Then you will get the validation error instead of posting a long string.

You can use **RegularExpressionValidator** and validation expression like **".{0,250}"** for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property of the textbox?

Comment: I guess its the problem with everybody, i think you have to rely on javascript for it, from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/130774/copy-paste.aspx#answer1)

Answer (score 0):

```
maxlength="250"
```

And you shouldnt be able to paste more than 250 chars.
That being said, its the browser that does the "counting/limiting" so it can be bypassed.
But then you could limit in the form submit or something

Otherwise you could do it with jquery. But maxlength should be enough?